# @ is not supporting to RIak Ts

Tags: riak-ts

while making query to Riak TS, my email contaning @ symbol so it giving some problem like

```
SQL Lexer error <<"Unexpected token '@'.">>
```

then How we Resolve this problem.

Comment: show your code first

Comment: while querying from riak-shell  simply its returning this  error, and my query is select SUM(steps),registrationDate from steps where start >= 1482085800000 and start <= 1489775400000 and userName = 'hussain.shahzad250@gmail.com';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query.

```
SELECT SUM(steps),
       registrationDate
FROM steps
WHERE
  START >= 1482085800000
  AND
  START <= 1489775400000
  AND userName = <<"hussain.shahzad250@gmail.com">>;
```

Comment: Sorry , it still having problem   as SQL Parser error {<<"<">>,riak_ql_parser,
                  ["syntax error before: ","less_than_operator"]}

Comment: Yes i got response but,  Now query will be like as select start,end,steps from steps_record where start >= 1472495400000 and start <= 1490121000000  and userName = '<<"hussain.shahzad250@gmail.com">>';

Comment: i am getting response but all time its returning  No rows returned. why ?? achually data is in my Riak TS DB.

Answer (score 0):

specially @Saranjith

Query will be now as given below

```
select start,end,steps from steps_record where start >= 1472495400000 and start <= 1490121000000  and userName = '<<"apolloprod120@gmail.com">>';
```

anyways Thanks @Saranjith, i tried with your given syntax in 2-3 ways after that i got this solved.

Comment: No rows returned as result by using above query  can anybody tell what is the problem.